# Webmachine with http and https?

Tags: https, erlang, mochiweb, webmachine

What is the recommended way of getting https working with webmachine?

I see that there is an example for getting mochiweb [working with https and http](http://code.google.com/p/mochiweb/source/browse/trunk/examples/https/https_store.erl?r=153). I just can seem to translate that to webmachine. In particular how do you handle both http and https requests in one app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i had some success getting multiple listeners with the following change to mywebdemo_sup.erl in the demo app.  i haven't tested it much further than that, but hopefully enough to get you started.

```
init([]) ->
    Ip = case os:getenv("WEBMACHINE_IP") of false -> "0.0.0.0"; Any -> Any end,
    {ok, Dispatch} = file:consult(filename:join(
                    [filename:dirname(code:which(?MODULE)),
                     "..", "priv", "dispatch.conf"])),
    WebConfig = [
         {name, one},
         {ip, Ip},
         {port, 8000},
         {log_dir, "priv/log"},
         {dispatch, Dispatch}],
    Web = {one,
       {webmachine_mochiweb, start, [WebConfig]},
       permanent, 5000, worker, dynamic},
    WebSSLConfig = [
            {name, two},
            {ip, Ip},
            {port, 8443},
            {ssl, true},
            {ssl_opts, [{certfile, "/tmp/api_server.crt"},
                {cacertfile,"tmp/api_server.ca.crt"},
                {keyfile, "/tmp/api_server.key"}]},
            {log_dir, "priv/log"},
            {dispatch, Dispatch}],
    WebSSL = {two,
          {webmachine_mochiweb, start, [WebSSLConfig]},
          permanent, 5000, worker, dynamic},
    Processes = [Web, WebSSL],
    {ok, { {one_for_one, 10, 10}, Processes} }.
```